# Axes tick label padding in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a pseudocolour image plot in Python Matplotlib, but I'm having a small problem with the layout- the axes tick labels are very small numbers (1e-7 or so), so Matplotlib puts an exponent on the entire axis. This is good, but it overlaps with the x axis label and the title!

[image: See how the title overlaps with "1e-7"!]

Is there a better way to fix this other than just hacking the title upwards and the xlabel downwards (and if this is the way to go, what's the best way to do this?) I'm trying to plot a lot of different things with maximal code reuse, so if Matplotlib has a way to fix this without channging text positioning manually that would be the best!

Here's how I'm generating this plot:

```
fig = Figure(figsize=(5.5, 4.25))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('The title', size=12)
ax.set_xlabel('The xlabel', size=10)
ax.set_ylabel('The Ylabel', size=10)
ax.ticklabel_format(scilimits=(-3,3))

pcm = ax.pcolor(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.jet) #X,Y is a meshgrid and Z is the function evaluated on it
ax.get_figure().colorbar(pcm, ax=ax, use_gridspec=True)
ax.set_axes([0, 1e-3, -5e-7, 5e-7])

#Some code for the hatching at the top and bottom of the plot

for ticklabel in ax.get_xticklabels():
    ticklabel.set_size(8)
for ticklabel in ax.get_yticklabels():
    ticklabel.set_size(8)
ax.get_xaxis().get_offset_text().set_size(8)
ax.get_yaxis().get_offset_text().set_size(8)
fig.subplots_adjust()
c = FigureCanvas(fig)
c.print_figure('filename.png', dpi=300)
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest approach is to remove the need for the exponents by multiplying X and Y by 1e3 and 1e7:

```
pcm = ax.pcolor(X*1e3, Y*1e7, Z, cmap=cm.jet)
```

then changing the labels to something like:

```
ax.set_xlabel('Longitudinal distance across waveguide ($10^{-3}$ m)', size=10)
ax.set_ylabel('Transverse distance across waveguide ($10^{-7}$ m)', size=10)
```

You can also change the tick labels directly or use  matplotlib.ticker.Formatter but the former is slightly more tedious while the latter is overkill.

Comment: You could automate this using `FuncFormatter` and a string formatting to make sure that your labels and ticks stay synced.

Comment: Could you tell me more about `FuncFormatter`?

Comment: I see, so you'd suggest doing something like using FuncFormatter to divide through by 10**floor(log10(x_max)), and just using a format string to include this number in the x-axis label?

Comment: That's the "overkill" method I was referring to because I expected that 10**floor(log10(x_max)) won't change in your data

Comment: Actually, the best answer I've had to this question was a comment by someone on my question to use `tight_layout`. However, this person deleted their comment! In any case, `tight_layout` seems to have stopped the x-axis label overlapping with the exponent.